# UNION - inconsistent datatype got CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that look like this

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

Of course not with these datas, but I will use it as an example

I need to use it as a inner join, where I can have each name as a column. 
It is a defined amount of rows, so that should not be a problem

I have tried to do it as

```
SELECT
  value AS a, 
  NULL as b
FROM ex
WHERE name = 'a'

UNION

SELECT
   NULL as a,
   value AS b 
FROM ex
WHERE name = 'b'
```

And so on, but I get the error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`

I have also tried with

```
 SELECT 
    CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN value ELSE NULL END AS a,
    CASE WHEN name = 'b' THEN value ELSE NULL END AS b
 FROM ex
 WHERE name IN ('a', 'b')
```

But the result from this is of course

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| NULL | 2 |

But I need to eliminate the NULL values, so I only have one row like

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

Does anybody have a good idea of how to solve this problem?

I can of course make 4 joins, but I was thinking, if it could be done in one join, as that will possibly be faster than look in the same table 4 times

Comment: What do you mean by eliminate the null values?

Comment: I just added that to the question

Comment: I suspect you've redacted the identifiers and it makes more sense with the original terms. It's by no means obvious what the rules are to go from the source table to the desired output. Are you trying to rotate (pivot) the original table for a fixed subset of `name` values? (if so, what is the sort order?). Do you have rows with `value` set to `NULL` in your table which you need to handle specifically (if so, how?) or `NULL` is just an artifact from your attempted queries?

Comment: So basically you need all the values by name?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, I am trying to pivot the original table for a fixed subset of `name` values. There are no order, as it has to be used in a join. `NULL` is just an artifact from the attempted queries. The column in the table is set to NOT NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the impression that you just want to get the value per name. Is this what you aim for:

```
WITH dat AS
(

  SELECT 'a' AS NAME, 1 AS VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 3 FROM dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM dat
         PIVOT (MAX(VALUE) FOR NAME IN ('a','b'))); -- list of the ones you need
```